# Building Bazel on a Windows machine

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to build bazel on a Windows machine, but `bazel build //src:bazel` does not find any target to build:

```
$ bazel build //src:bazel
Loading:
Loading: 0 packages loaded
INFO: Analysed 0 targets (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 0 targets...
[0 / 1] [-----] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.389s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

To be clear: This is happening only with *master*, I was able to build the 0.10.1 dist version of Bazel (from github) on my Windows machine.

To make sure my 0.10.1 binary is okay I built the cpp example (//examples/cpp:hello-world). It worked as expected - no failures.

I was able to build a stable dist version (namely, 0.10.1)bazel *master* on a Linux and macOS machines.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which commit did you check out from the Bazel repository? (See `git rev-parse HEAD`) Which Bazel version are you using? (See `bazel version`)

Comment: I just tried this at current HEAD ([`c91bd9270`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/c91bd9270d1a199d8daeb7fbc41762e9547b0d7c)) and I can successfully build Bazel from source on Windows 10 version 1607, using 0.11.0rc1.

Comment: @László I used af24688e4e0c8c359a2ec7af3fffaa1c825ef7ed to build. I was able to build the `dist` archive, the problem occurs when I try to build from scratch the code from _master_

Comment: Tried again with 4ee8f5d79f49dd3592e27b43528535b67f449625, same problem: `Found 0 targets`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are running Bazel from MSYS Bash. This is no longer necessary, because Bazel is a native Windows binary since version 0.5.0.

MSYS thinks the argument `//src:bazel` is a Unix-style path (because it starts with `/`) so it converts the "path" for Bazel to a Windows path. IIRC the conversion logic just removes one `/` and the target pattern ends up being `/src:bazel`.

As a solution, I suggest one of the following:

- Run Bazel from `cmd.exe` or from Powershell. This is how I use Bazel and it works as expected.
- Disable the path conversion heuristic in MSYS:

  `export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
  export MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="*"`
- Use `///` instead of `//` in the target path. This only works under MSYS and I don't think it's reliable because I don't understand MSYS's path conversion logic, so I don't recommend this solution but here it is anyway:

  `bazel build ///src:bazel`

Comment: That's correct, I am using MSYS. This is seems to be the official build environment in bazel docs: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-compile-source.html :
`On Windows, do following steps in the msys2 shell`

Comment: Yes, that's still correct! The document fails to mention however that you only need to use msys2 shell for compiling Bazel from source without using a released Bazel binary (= bootstrapping). If you already have Bazel that you can use to build stuff (including Bazel itself, from source), then you can use cmd.exe